# Unity project failed to build using Mono

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono

I cannot build my project In mono mode. It works but no `Il2cpp` please help

### 1. ERROR

> Failed running C: \ Program Files \ Unity 2019.3.0b4 \ Editor \ Data \ il2cpp \ build / UnityLinker.exe -out = C: / shamstest / Temp / StagingArea / assets / bin / Data / Managed / tempStrip -x = C: /shamstest/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/../platform_native_link.xml -x = C: /shamstest/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/TypesInScenes.xml -d = C: / shamstest / Temp / StagingArea / assets / bin / Data / Managed --dotnetruntime = il2cpp --dotnetprofile = unityaot --use-editor-options --include-directory = C: / shamstest / Temp / StagingArea / assets / bin / Data / Managed --rule-set = Conservative --editor-data-file = C: /shamstest/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed/EditorToUnityLinkerData.json --platform = Android --enable-engine-module- stripping --engine-stripping-flag = EnableUnityConnect --engine-modules-asset-file = "C: / Program Files / Unity 2019.3.0b4 / Editor / Data / PlaybackEngines / AndroidPlayer / Whitelists /../ modules.asset"

stdout: stderr:

> √ 2.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 "���� ���� �� �� ����ᨬ��⥩. �� 㤠 ���� ���� 㪠 ����� 䠩 �.     � Unity.Linker.UnityDriver..ctor (String [] args)     � Unity.Linker.Program.Main (String [] args)
>
> UnityEngine.Debug: LogError (Object) UnityEditorInternal.Runner: RunProgram (Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) UnityEditorInternal.Runner: RunManagedProgram (String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action1) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper: RunAssemblyLinker (IEnumerable1, String &, String &, String, String) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper: StripAssembliesTo (String, String &, String &, IEnumerable1, UnityLinkerRunInformation) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper: RunAssemblyStripper (UnityLinkerRunInformation) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper: StripAssemblies (String, BaseUnityLinkerPlatformProvider, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, RuntimeClassRegistry, ManagedStrippingLevel) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder: Run () UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils: RunIl2Cpp (String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action1, RuntimeClassRegistry) UnityEngine.GUIUtility: ProcessEvent (Int32, IntPtr)

### 2.ERROR

> Exception: C: \ Program Files \ Unity 2019.3.0b4 \ Editor \ Data \ il2cpp \ build / UnityLinker.exe did not run properly! UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at <5f8e991dd2b8dbbddbbdbbd441) UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1 [T] setupStartInfo) (at <5f8e8d7a2d2e2a2d2e1d2e2a2d2e1d2a2d2e2d1d2a2d1d2a2d1d2a2d1d2a2d1d2a2d1d2a2d1d2d1d2a7d2d2a7e2d1d2a7d2a) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyLinker (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 [T] args, System.String & out, System.String & err, System.String linkerPath, System.String workingDirectory) (at 0a8a8a8a8aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssembliesTo (System.String outputFolder, System.String & output, System.String & error, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 [T] linkXmlFiles, UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRa88dd1e8ad8ad1a8ad1a8bd1d1a8bd1d8ad1e8ad1a8bd1d1a_db8d1_8bd1_db1d1_fd2_db_db_db_db_db_db_db_file_function_files UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (UnityEditorInternal.UnityLinkerRunInformation runInformation) (at : 0) UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.BaseUnityLinkerPlatformProvider unityLinkerPlatformProvider, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider il2cppPlatformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at : 0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at : 0) UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1 [T] modifyityutfd8e8dre1drreg1dreme8dreg1dre1dremelass_megregor UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at : 0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at : 0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEptions, Unitityptor

Comment: This is a better question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Install Net Framework 4.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net472-developer-pack-offline-installer

It worked for me